# Using Spyder with Anaconda in a venv

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, python-venv

I'm under Linux Mint 20.3 and I installed Anaconda in order to use Jupyter Notebook and Spyder.

I created a venv in Anaconda with the left menu "Environments", I named it "testEnv" and choose a python version.

Then in a terminal I activated the venv with the command line `conda activate testEnv`.
I verified the installed packages with `pip freeze` in order to check if my environment was empty.

I saw that a lot of packages are preinstalled !

```
certifi==2021.10.8
click==8.1.3
Flask==2.1.2
Flask-Pydantic==0.9.0
importlib-metadata==4.11.3
itsdangerous==2.1.2
Jinja2==3.1.2
MarkupSafe==2.1.1
pydantic==1.9.0
typing_extensions==4.2.0
Werkzeug==2.1.2
```

So how to deal with this packages ? I don't want to see them in my requirements.txt because my Python application don't use them !

In order to use SPyder in my testEnv environment, I choose "install Spyder" in the Anaconda main window while testEnv environment was selected in the left menu.

It installed in my testEnv a lot of other packages !

What did I miss ? How to use Spyder with Anaconda in a venv without any preinstalled packages ?

Comment: I'm guessing it used conda to install Spyder in the environment, which is a python project, so it installed the dependencies of Spyder

Comment: Spyder has *many* dependencies.  The requirements files should only show the libraries used by the project itself, *not* everything installed in the venv.  For example, the library `pipreqs` functions for way.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga yes I agree but how to hide this spyder dependencies in my project requirement ???

Comment: @S3DEV yes I agree but how to hide this spyder dependencies in my project requirement ??? (sorry for the repeated comment)